# CSS issue with Table inside div in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table which I need to display beside the "datepicker" in HTML but it is displaying below to the "datepicker" i.e. in next line.

I am trying to figure this out not able to get.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <br/>
<div id="datepicker" style="float:left;"></div>

<div id="main" style="float: left; width:87%; height:700px; margin-left:5px; margin-top:0px;">
<div id="doclist">
 </div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="tabs">
        <!-- Tabs go here -->
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- Tab content goes here -->

    <div id="table">
    <table style="height:500px">

      //Table code starts from here.
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and Here is my CSS :

```
body { font-family:Lucida Sans, Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial, Sans-Serif;    font-size:13px; margin:0px auto;}
  #tabs { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; overflow:hidden; }
  #tabs li { float:left; margin-left:4px; display:block; padding:10px; background-color:#8AE62E; margin-right:0px;}
  #tabs li a { color:#fff; text-decoration:none; }
  #tabs li.current { background-color:#C16CC1;  height:18px}
  #tabs li.current a { color:#000;  text-decoration:none; }
  #tabs li a.remove { color:#f00;  margin-left:10px;}
  #content { background-color:#e1e1e1; }
  #content p { margin: 0; padding:20px 20px 100px 20px;}

  #main { width:1050px; height:500px; margin:0px auto; overflow:hidden;background-color:#F6F6F6;  margin-top:0px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;  -webkit-border-radius:10px; padding:0px;}
  #wrapper, #doclist { float:left; margin:0 0px 0 0;}
  #doclist { width:150px; border-right:solid 1px #dcdcdc;}
  #doclist ul { margin:0; list-style:none;}
  #doclist li { margin:10px 0; padding:0;}
  #documents { margin:0; padding:0;}

  #wrapper { width:1200px; margin-top:0px;}

  #header{ background-color:#F6F6F6;  width:900px; margin:0px auto; margin-top:0px;
     -moz-border-radius:10px;  -webkit-border-radius:10px; padding:30px; position:relative;}
  #header h2 {font-size:16px; font-weight:normal; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
```

Comment: Thats quite a lot of code- can you create a jsfiddle.net? It will help isolate the issue faster

Comment: It would be really helpful if you'd create a JsFiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Your datepicker goes in the content div?
Div's by default fill the entire width' of the screen, you could go with someting like:
#table, #content {display:inline-block}; so they would align next to eachother.

Comment: @MathijsSegers What i should write instead of this ..<div id="datepicker" style="float:left;

Comment: Try adding it after the table div :). Create a JSfiddle perhaps